# Insertar símbolo de subida o bajada con respecto al precio si es negativo o positivo

Tags: python

estoy trabajando en un bot de telegram para llevar precios de tickers... Queria realizar la siguente accion:
Cuando el precio es negativo, agregar un Unicode o un DownArrow y cuando el precio es positivo agregar un UpArrow. Ejemplo:
MSFT $240.45 ((uparrow) 2.45%) o MSFT $240.45 ((downarrow) 2.45%)

El codigo hasta el momento del message, es el siguente

```
    respuesta = ""
respuesta += f"\u23B0{empresas} \u0024{CloseX} \u2063{Change} ( \u00B1 {PercentChange} )\n\u00A92021 @ST4Helper\nPowered by Yahoo Finance!\n......................."
context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=respuesta)
```

Comment: Hola. Te faltó decirnos qué problema tienes con ese código?

Comment: Hola!. No tiene ningun problema, solo es saber de que manera puede definir el UpArrow o DownArrow dependiendo de si el precio es negativo o positivo

Answer (score 1):

Con el uso de operador ternario puedes hacerlo muy simple. Por ejemplo

```py
precio = -90.8
message = f"el precio es {precio} {'downarrow' if precio<0 else 'uparrow'}"
```

La sintaxis es simple.

```
<valor_verdadero> if <condicion> else <valor_falso>
```